# Ignore redundant values fetched from database

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle11g, duplicates

Following is the sample o/p of the SQL query -

```
  BUG_ID   |  LINKED_BUG_ID
-----------|-----------------
3726       |  45236
45236      |  3726
3726       |  45254
45254      |  3726
3726       |  45402
45402      |  3726
3726       |  1182
1182       |  55745
```

In my SQL o/p,  there are two rows  out of which one row is redundant. e.g *Bug Id* **3726** and *Linked Bug Id* **45326** and *Bug Id* **45326** and *Linked Bug Id* **3726** are present twice in the o/p, out of which we need only one row and ignore such kind of **duplicate rows** (having either of a value repeated in *Bug Id* column or *Linked Bug Id* column), without affecting the o/p containing the distinct value.

Currently I can identify such **duplicate rows** using following query, but I need only one single row out of such duplicate rows.

```
SELECT 
  BUG_ID, 
  LINKED_BUG_ID, 
  CASE 
    WHEN BUG_ID IN (select LINKED_BUG_ID FROM MY_BUG_LINKS) AND 
      LINKED_ISSUE_ID IN (SELECT BUG_ID FROM MY_BUG_LINKS) 
    THEN 'true' ELSE 'false'  
  END AS EQUAL 
FROM MY_BUG_LINKS;
```

Following is the SQL query that I use in my code for fetching all the rows (which includes even duplicate rows)

```
SELECT BUG_ID, LINKED_BUG_ID FROM MY_BUG_LINKS;
```

How can I avoid fetching redundant duplicate rows at the database level itself or in my java code?

Comment: If the row is redundant, why not remove it from the database? Why is it there in the first place?

Comment: Is it only for one-away forward and back links `{(A, B), (B, A)}`, or are you looking to eliminate duplicates connected in a chain, as in `{(A, B), (B, C), (C, D), (D, A)}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is merely about treating `(B, A)` as a duplicate of `(A, B)` and you do not particularly care whether the row returned will be `(A, B)` or `(B, A)`, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  CASE WHEN BUG_ID > LINKED_BUG_ID THEN LINKED_BUG_ID ELSE BUG_ID AS BUG_ID,
  CASE WHEN BUG_ID > LINKED_BUG_ID THEN BUG_ID ELSE LINKED_BUG_ID AS LINKED_BUG_ID
FROM MY_BUG_LINKS;
```

That is, if `BUG_ID` has a greater value than `LINKED_BIG_ID`, the query swaps the two IDs, otherwise the values are returned unchanged. Therefore, `(A, B)` and `(B, A)` always produce duplicate rows (both would be either `(A, B)` or `(B, A)`), and `DISTINCT` makes sure there's none in the final result.

Answer (score 0):

you may try something similar to this:

```
select 
distinct bug_id from
(
    select bug_id as bug_id from TABLE
 union
    select linked_bug_id as bug_id from TABLE
)
```