# How to skip duplicate value while fetching from My sql DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have one problem.I am fetching some data from MYSQL table.But there are some duplicate datas. I need to skip those duplicate data.I am explaining my code below.

```
session_start();
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$colg_id=1;
$dept_id = $_SESSION["admin_dept_id"];
$user_id=$_SESSION["admin_id"];
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "******", "go_fasto");
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "select plan_id,unit_name  from db_unit_plan where dept_id='".$dept_id."'  and user_id = '".$user_id."'   ");
while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $data[] = $row;
}
    print json_encode($data);
```

Here i need if any unit_name column has same type  data then how to skip those rows.Please help me.

Comment: Maybe use `SELECT DISTINCT` ?

Comment: Like rMX says, check out [SELECT DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Comment: select plan_id,distinct(unit_name) ? not sure but give it a try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore redundant values fetched from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073054/ignore-redundant-values-fetched-from-database)

Answer (score 1):

Change like this with DISTINCT

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "select DISTINCT unit_name,plan_id  from db_unit_plan where dept_id='".$dept_id."'  and user_id = '".$user_id."'   ");
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify the 'DISTINCT' keyword to get unique results from SQL. 
so just try changing your select statement to `$result = mysqli_query($connect, "select DISTINCT plan_id .. ");`

good luck.